# spirit qi grammar issues

Tags: c++, boost, grammar, boost-spirit-qi

First of all, sorry for the inaccurate title, it's just that I don't actually know whats causing the compilation error ( Im new to spirit/phoenix/tuple ), hence for readability of my question I exported the entire grammar to pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/RsGM8E4r

The code is compiled in Visual Studio 2010 with:

```
Iterator = std::string::const_iterator
```

and other information you need to understand the grammar and my question at the bottom:

```
namespace parser { namespace container1 {

    template < typename _C >
    class atom : public element < _C >
    {
        private:
            typedef typename std::basic_string < _C >       _string;

        public:
            explicit atom ( const boost::variant < bool, long, double, _string > & value )
            :   _value ( value )
            {
                    _element_type = TY_ATOM;
            }

            explicit atom ()
            {

            }

            template < typename T >
            const T as () const
            {
                return boost::apply_visitor ( atom_visitor < _C, T > (), _value );
            }

        private:
            boost::variant < bool, long, double, _string >  _value;
    };

    template < typename _C >
    struct item
    {
        typedef typename element < _C >                 type;
        typedef typename boost::shared_ptr < type >     ptr;
    };
}}
```

group and list also have element as base.

Now, the thing I don't understand is, when you look at the grammar, the rule definition for atom is:

```
atom =
    ( qi::double_ | qi::long_ | qi::bool_ | string )    [ qi::_val = phoenix::construct < _item_ptr > ( phoenix::new_ < _atom > ( qi::_1 ) ) ]
;
```

This gives a very long list of compiler error which I can't really comprehend .. exported to pastebin again: http://pastebin.com/k4HseJ01

If I however change the rule to

```
atom =
    ( qi::double_ | qi::long_ | qi::bool_ | string )    [ qi::_val = phoenix::construct < _item_ptr > ( phoenix::new_ < _atom > () ) ]
;
```

it compiles successfully, but well I need to get the parsed data from that rule :P

Thank you very much in advance for any help, I'm really stuck at that for days.